# Trying to import vk.core.api in Java

Tags: java, gradle, import

I'm trying to import vk.core.api in Java but when I try to compile it, I get only errors like "error: package vk.core.api does not exist
import vk.core.api.*;"

```
package main.java.tddt;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import main.java.tddt.data.Log;
import main.java.tddt.data.LogList;
import main.java.tddt.data.Timer;
import main.java.tddt.gui.Controller;
import vk.core.api.*;
import vk.core.api.CompilerResult;
import vk.core.api.TestResult;
import vk.core.api.CompileError;
import vk.core.api.CompilerFactory;
import vk.core.api.JavaStringCompiler;
import vk.core.internal.*;
import vk.core.internal.InternalResult;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the dependencies of your `build.gradle` something like:

```
compile group: 'de.hhu.stups', name: 'virtual-kata-lib', version: '1.0.0'
```

Comment: Is it possible that the build.gradle file doesn't exist per default? I can't find it in the root, not anywhere.

Comment: Since you did mention gradle in the tags of your question, I assumed you used Gradle. Maybe you don't. Do you have a build system such as Gradle or Maven to support your project?

Comment: I'm actually working with someone and now I'm convinced that gradle wasn't in use as I expected.

Comment: Then you'll have to download virtual-kata-lib manually from here http://central.maven.org/maven2/de/hhu/stups/virtual-kata-lib/1.0.0/ and fill the classpath with a dependency on the JAR file.